# Twig date filter not working with DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2, twig

I'm using CI2 with Doctrine2 and Twig for the template engine. I'm trying to display the date from an entity as a string, however it's not working for me.

I'm sending an array of Entity objects to the template, iterating through them, and displaying their properties:

```
{% for e in entities %}
    <span><label>username</label>{{e.getUserName}}</span>
    <span><label>email</label>{{e.getEmail}}</span>
    <span><label>date created</label>{{e.getCreatedAt | date('d.M.Y H:i:s')}}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

The `getCreatedAt()` method returns a DateTime object. I can use this object just fine from within PHP:

```
echo $e->getCreatedAt->format('YmdHis');
```

However from within Twig I can't seem to find any way to get a string printed. When I try the above way (which I've read is the correct way to do it) I get:

```
date() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

I've tried several other methods:

```
{{e.getCreatedAt.format('d.M.Y H:i:s')}}
{{e.getCreatedAt}}
{{e.getCreatedAt | date('d.M.Y H:i:s') |strtotime}}
```

Nothing works out.

I was sure to add the 'date' Twig filter using the addFilter() method:

```
$this->twig->addFilter('date', Twig_Filter_Function('date'));
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` is a built-in filter, you need not register it, especially not to the php `date` function, which cannot handle DateTime objects.

Comment: Strange, I'd tried several times before registering the date filter, and was having no luck. Now, I've removed the filter and it's working. I'll chalk it up to lack of sleep :) thanks,