# Date gives as result 2024 instead of 1924 Twig

Tags: php, date, datetime, twig

In the database, I have following date: `1924-01-17`, as a date-type, but when I render it as `{{ person.BirthDate | date("d/m/Y") }}`, it gives as a result `17/01/2024`.

How can I solve the Year-problem?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's a formatting issue, have you tried to convert it into a unixtimestamp and then try to display the date through the date("d/m/Y") ?

Comment: "have you tried to convert it into a unixtimestamp" --- unix timestamp era starts in year 1970

Comment: @zerkms Ah yes of course, my mind is still stuck in the morning traffic.

Comment: This is your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871264/using-strtotime-for-dates-before-1970

Comment: @divaka is it? "The date filter accepts strings (it must be in a format supported by the strtotime function), DateTime instances, or DateInterval instances.", I guess DateTime instances could also be used here.

Comment: DateTime instance works fine... Thanks!

Comment: @eis You are right. I've rushed a little bit :) Referring this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792246/twig-date-filter-not-working-with-datetime-object "`date` is a built-in filter, you need not register it, especially not to the php `date` function, which cannot handle DateTime objects". So indeed DateTime instances will do trick.

Comment: @user2365583 great! added it as an answer.

Comment: @zerkms most libs will manage negative timestamps

Answer (score 2):

[Twig documentation for date](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) says:

> The date filter accepts strings (it must be in a format supported by
>   the strtotime function), DateTime instances, or DateInterval
>   instances.

DateTime instance should do the trick, and based on comments it fixed this.